# vertex jar not found exception even after the jar is present

Tags: maven, vert.x

org.vertx.java.platform.PlatformManagerException: Module io.vertx~lang-groovy~2.0.0-final not found in any repositories
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.getModule(DefaultPlatformManager.java:985)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doInstallMod(DefaultPlatformManager.java:974)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.loadIncludedModules(DefaultPlatformManager.java:858)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.doDeploy(DefaultPlatformManager.java:1219)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.deployModuleFromModJson(DefaultPlatformManager.java:742)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.deployModuleFromFileSystem(DefaultPlatformManager.java:812)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager.access$100(DefaultPlatformManager.java:55)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$1.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:151)
    at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.DefaultPlatformManager$11.run(DefaultPlatformManager.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was io.vertx~lang-groovy~2.0.0-final folder was missing after compiling of project.
It was missing because the vertx was not able to fetch the jar from maven as maven has stopped support to http from january 15 2020.